# How to display List as DropdownList in ASP MVC5 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I want to display list of roles as drop down.

```
List<IdentityRole> roles = ContextManager.getApplicationDbContext().Roles.ToList();
IdentityRole defaultRole = roles.Find(item => item.Id == "salesManId");
ViewBag.Role = new SelectList(roles, "Role", "Role", defaultRole);
```

My razor code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Role", ViewBag.Role)
        </div>
    </div>
```

But its not working. Can anyone tell me the issue?

Comment: ViewBag.Role = new SelectList(roles, "Role", "Role"); for now I have removed default role. But its still not working.

Comment: Yes my model does contain a property string Role.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IdentityRole_968BF86C9FBE492848105A78DCDCF79FA2CCC16CCD748C22DF4D87AC8EC09038' does not contain a property with the name 'Role'.

Comment: Oh! True that was the issue.

Comment: No I want value and display name to be changed. So I did this: IdentityRole defaultRole = roles.Find(item => item.Id == "managerId");
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Name", defaultRole); and now its showing: <select id="Role" name="Role" class="valid"><option value="managerId">Manager</option>
<option value="salesManId">Sales Man</option>
<option value="superAdminId">Super Admin</option>
</select> which is what I wanted

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you please ans the question what you have wriiten in comment? So that I can mark it as answer :)

Comment: You are right. But I want to give the default value to be selected how can I do that?

Comment: If you ask me to add the answer, at least have the courtesy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`IdentityRole` does not contain a property named `Role`, (but it does have one named `Name` for the name of the role) and since you also using the same value for both the options `value` attribute and display text, then you controller code should be just

```
IEnumerable<string> roles = ContextManager.getApplicationDbContext().Roles.Select(r > r.Name);
ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(roles);
```

Note that the `ViewBag` name should not be the same as the name of the property your binding to. Then in the view, use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleList)
```

and if the value of your property `Role` matches one of the values of the options, then it will be selected when the view is generated.

Edit

Based on your comments, you want to bind to the `Id` property of `IdentityRole` in which case the code needs to be

```
IEnumerable<IdentityRole> roles = ContextManager.getApplicationDbContext().Roles;
ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Name");
```

and to select the default value when the view is generated

```
model.Role = roles.Where(r => r.Id == "salesManId").Select(r => r.Id);
// or just model.Role = "salesManId";
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<IdentityRole> roles = ContextManager.getApplicationDbContext().Roles.ToList();
IdentityRole defaultRole = roles.Find(item => item.Id == "salesManId");
ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(roles, "Role", "Role", defaultRole);


<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("RoleList")
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Still not working. An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IdentityRole_968BF86C9FBE492848105A78DCDCF79FA2CCC16CCD748C22DF4D87AC8EC09038' does not contain a property with the name 'Role'.

Comment: You need to change the ViewBag property name. Find the updated code and try